# How to return multiple elements at a regular interval in Python?

Tags: python, slice

I have an array of monthly data I am trying to examine by season.  I have 851 months (71 years) but want to only select meteorological spring for all years (March, April, and May), where January = 0.

I know that I can select every March, for example, by slicing `data[2::12]`, but how would I select every March, April and May together?

So for example, if I have `[0,1,2,3,4,5,...,22,23,24]` (24 months), I want to return `[2,3,4,14,15,16]` (March, April and May for both years).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to stackoverflow

I would try a list comprehension:

```
[monthly_data for i, monthly_data in enumerate(all_data) if i%12 in (2,3,4)]
```

What this does is to pick every `monthly_data` item in your `all_data` sequence, as long as the remainder of the division of its index `i` by 12 is either 2, 3 or 4.

Answer (score 0):

You could for example, loop through all the indexes/values in your list and test if the index of a given item is a multiple of your selected months (2, 3, 4)

```
res = []
spring_months = [2, 3, 4]
for index, value in enumerate(data):
    if index%12 in spring_months:
        res.append(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list slicing in a nested list comprehension:

```
m = list(range(24))
print([j for i in range(2, len(m), 12) for j in m[i:i+3]])
```

This outputs:

```
[2, 3, 4, 14, 15, 16]
```